# phase portrait of linear system and normal vector

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> given the following system
> $\left\{\begin{array}
> >x_1'=cx_2-bx_3\\x_2'=-cx_1+ax_3\\x_3'=bx_1-ax_2\end{array}\right.$
> and we know that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=1$ prove that all the phase portrait of the system are close curves which belongs to parallels planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$and find the normal vector to these plane

I've found that the eigenvalues are $0,\pm i$ but I never delt with 3d phase portrait.
any hint please?

Answer (score 0):

Your system can be written using the cross product as
$$
\dot {\vec v}=\vec v\times \vec n,~~\vec v=\pmatrix{x\\y\\z},~\vec n=\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}.
$$
It immediately follows that the scalar product with the factors has to give zero on the right and thus also on the left, so that
$$
r^2=\vec v·\vec v~\text{ and }~ d=\vec n·\vec v
$$
are constants. The solutions thus lie in the plane given by the second equation, and on the sphere given by the first equation. The intersection of both are circles.